# Load all xaml files(workflows + activities) from disk

Tags: xaml, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

We created some workflows xamls that contains other sub-workflows xamls, and we deploy them (both workflows and sub-workflows) in a specific folder.  Our user can modify those xamls (both workflows and sub-workflows) without recompiling if it is not necessary.

Currently we load the workflows from the disk using ActivityXamlServices, so it covers the case when we modify the workflows, but it doesn't when the sub-workflow is modified, and we have to recompile the project.

This is a simple scenario:
Workflow.xaml that contains Activity1:

```
<Activity mc:Ignorable="sap" x:Class="Workflows.Workflow" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="240,240" mva:VisualBasic.Settings="Assembly references and imported namespaces for internal implementation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities" xmlns:a="clr-namespace:ActivityLibrary;assembly=ActivityLibrary" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:mv="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic;assembly=System" xmlns:mva="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities;assembly=System.Activities" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:s1="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System" xmlns:s2="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Xml" xmlns:s3="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Core" xmlns:sad="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Debugger;assembly=System.Activities" xmlns:sap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities/presentation" xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System" xmlns:scg1="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System.ServiceModel" xmlns:scg2="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System.Core" xmlns:scg3="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:sd="clr-namespace:System.Data;assembly=System.Data" xmlns:sl="clr-namespace:System.Linq;assembly=System.Core" xmlns:st="clr-namespace:System.Text;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
```

Activity1.xaml:

```
<Activity x:Class="ActivityLibrary.Activity1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities" mva:VisualBasic.Settings="Assembly references and imported namespaces for internal implementation" xmlns:mv="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic;assembly=System" xmlns:mva="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities;assembly=System.Activities" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:s1="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System" xmlns:s2="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Xml" xmlns:s3="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Core" xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System" xmlns:scg1="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System.ServiceModel" xmlns:scg2="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System.Core" xmlns:scg3="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:sd="clr-namespace:System.Data;assembly=System.Data" xmlns:sl="clr-namespace:System.Linq;assembly=System.Core" xmlns:st="clr-namespace:System.Text;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
```

If we modify Activity1.xaml we must recompile now... <-- Avoid this!
The solution that I'm thinking is compile on runtime using XamlBuildTask.. Do you think it is the right solution to follow? Other options?

Thanks in advance!